# ZK : forwarding action with paramether

Tags: parameters, forwarding, zk

I am trying to show and hide rows dynamically on my page.firstly I tryed to make it on .zul page but I could not refresh component with annotadeDatabinder. Now I am trying to make it on controller java file but now I am facing with problem that  if I use for component(like listbox) `forward ="onSelect=onSelected(paramA)"`   then on controller I am tringto catch it like

`public void onSelected(ForwardEvent event , String pram){ }`  this does not work.If I use without second parameter it works. But I should send some string to check it. İs there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the event listener is wrong. It shall be the same no matter the parameter is specified or not. Furthermore, the parameter you passed could be retrieved from event.getData().

```
public void onSelected(ForwardEvent event) {
  String param = (String)event.getData();
...
```